# DateTime Libraries and Date Interval Placement

Tags: c++, datetime, libraries

This is more of a general theory question but I figure I should give some context anyway.

I'm in the middle of writing a program. The basic gist is that I have 2 dat files. In fileA.dat each line is a timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and a bit of data. In fileB.dat each line is two timestamps in the format DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS.

The idea is that the program will create a bunch more dat files, one corresponding to each pair from fileB.dat. Whenever the timestamp from a line in fileA.dat lands between the two timestamps of a pair line from fileB.dat, the whole line from fileA.dat will be written to the new dat file corresponding to the pair-stamps. Makes sense?

Nothing crazy about the program save maybe how the timestamps use different formats. I just heard there's a way to handle this without having to "reinvent the wheel" using inherent c++ library that I don't know about.

Curious to know more.

-J

Edit:- Didn't end up learning anything that actually seemed useful for my project, maybe I'm just not getting it. I don't know. What I do know is that I tried some test code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

  // Read from jet_full [C - (Date, Time), Data] - Cycle
  std::ifstream FullFile;
  FullFile.open("jet_full.txt");
  if(!FullFile)
    {
      std::cout << "Error opening file. \n";
      std::cout << "It may not exist where indicated" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
  
  int run = 0;
  int a, b ; 
  while(!FullFile.eof()){
    FullFile >> a >> b ;
    run++;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << run << std::endl;
  // Create jet_run_XXX.dat
  //  ofstream runsplit;
  //  runsplit.open("jet_run_" >> run >> ".txt");
    
  // Read from jet_run_times.dat [A - (Date, Time), B - (Date, Time)] - Cycle
  // Check if A < C and C < B
  // If yes, write [C - (Date, Time), Data] to jet_run_XXX.dat
  // Cycle through all jet_run_times.dat
  // Cycle through all jet_full
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is an ever growing number of lines that all read

```
0 0 [Run Number]
```

I don't understand why I'm only getting Zeros when I'm trying to read the double time stamps per line file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which wheel are you seeking to not reinvent, the parsing of the timestamps?

Comment: If we're thinking about the same thing that would be a big one, yes. You're talking about how the compiler reads and readies the timestamps/dates for comparison I assume?

Comment: Absl library has dayetime parsing code iirc. `absl::ParseTime` maybe

Comment: Howard Hinnant's excellent date library (built on chrono) can parse your dates.  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

Comment: Note if you are compiling to C++20 or better, not that there currently is an official better, Hinnant's date library is , more or less, built in.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a C++20, going to have to look into this either way it seems.

Comment: And got an update. Basically I decided to just go for it and reinvent the wheel anyway but the output of a test doesn't make any sense.